# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})?

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, yup

```
  **Reack_formik**
```

I am trying to validate my form field with **Formik** , but I am getting the error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}), I saw the same error questions  already been asked but in my case I was not able to figure it out So I decided to ask here. First I want to know where is the error my code ,second mostly I am facing this error , Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}), so what does actually   mean by this error. Your help will be highly appreciated I am trying to figure it out from yesterday but I am not able to solve

---

```
import React from 'react'
         import {Formik,Form,Field, ErrorMessage} from "formik"
         import * as  Yup from 'yup' 
         const FormikComponent = () => {
         const initialValues= {
                name:"",
                email:"",
                password:""
            }
         const onSubmit=values=>{
                console.log("Values after submission", values)
            }
            const validationSchema=Yup.object({
                name:Yup.string().required("Requried"),
                email:Yup.string().email("inavlid email formate").required("required"),
                password:Yup.string().required("required")
            })
        return (
            <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} 
                           onSubmit= {onSubmit}>
                 <Form action="">
                     <div className="form-control">
                     <label htmlFor="name">name</label>
                     <Field type="text" name="name" id="name"  />
                     <ErrorMessage name="name"/> 
                     </div>
                     <div className="form-control">
                     <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
                     <Field type="email" name="email" id="email"   />
                     <ErrorMessage email="email"/>
                     </div>
                     <div className="form-control">
                     <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                     <Field type="Password" name="password" id="password" />
                     <ErrorMessage password="password"/>
                     </div>
                     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                 </Form>
            </Formik>
        )
    }
    export default FormikComponent ;
```

---

```
      **App.js**


 import './App.css';
import FormikComponent from './Formik4';
function App() {
  return (
       <div className="main">
         <h1>React form</h1>
         {<FormikComponent/>}
       </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: first of all <ErrorMessage /> only accepts name and render props not email or password props as you have mentioned in the code. try to fix it first and see if it working or not.

Comment: yes bro it is working now Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Error is appearing due to incorrectly written error component

```
<ErrorMessage email="email"/>
```

should have been written as

```
<ErrorMessage name="email"/>
```

Comment: Yeah Exactly I just noticed that now, Thanks for your help bro